# How do I query a Dom element in Angular2 Dart?

Tags: dart, angular

In AngularDart I used to extend `ShadowRootAware` and `AttachAware` to query the document with `shadowRoot.querySelector(...)`.

Now it seems that those classes are gone. How can I query the DOM, and how do I execute some code in the "attach" phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found

```
var shadowRoot = DOM.getShadowRoot(host);
```

`shadowRoot` should allow you to call `querySelector()`

Not tried myself yet though.

Comment: in the context of a component, what would be `host`? Is it referring to `this` ?

Comment: Seems like my component isn't an element. I get this `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Class 'AppComp' has no instance getter 'shadowRoot'.` when calling `var shadowRoot = DOM.getShadowRoot(this);` and `DOM.getShadowRoot(this)` is implemented like this `ShadowRoot getShadowRoot(Element el) => el.shadowRoot;`

Comment: Do you get a reference to the element if you add an argument to the constructor to get it injected? http://victorsavkin.com/post/126514197956/dependency-injection-in-angular-1-and-angular-2 (INJECTING THE COMPONENT’S ELEMENT)